# "But from" or "But rather from"?

Tags: prepositions, syntactic-analysis, conjunctions, prepositional-phrases

Which one is more grammatically correct? **But from** or **But rather from**?

I don't quite understand which one should be used. And I seriously doubt that the second one can be used at all.

> It didn't occur because of this, *but rather from* this.
>
> It didn't occur because of this, *but from* this.

Comment: I believe that both are somewhat grammatical  'rather' and 'from' can be interchangeable in your situation

Comment: @anonymous Can there ever be a situation in which one is preferred over the other?

Comment: I also believe that in most situations, 'but rather from' is highly more preferred and considered to be more "proper" and sophisticated.

Comment: As others have said, both are acceptable.  I would suggest that the inclusion of 'rather' emphasises the comparison.  Additionally, the difference between "*because* of this" and "*from* this" seems a bit odd (depending what *this* would be replaced by).  I would normally expect the same terminology in both clauses: "It didn't occur because of this, but rather *because of* this."

Answer (score 2):

Some comments to this effect have already been made, but I'd like to build on them.

1. Both forms are grammatically correct.
2. In formal written English, the "rather" form looks more elegant.
3. I would suggest that the elegance argument is less important than the flow of the sentence. Your sentence is already a short one, and without the flow of text before and after it, I can't say how well it would read either way. Once it has been established that both forms are grammatically correct, I would suggest that the next stage is to see whether the significant lengthening of the sentence adds to or detracts from its readability.